# Is there a StackExchange forum for French?

Tags: discussion

That would be convenient if we have different languages under stackExchange groups...

Comment: @Mitch - Considering that my question have gained -7 downvote and considering that you have definited that a "poor question", what would you do with this question?

Comment: Maybe this will be of assistance - http://french.stackexchange.com/ - Thats for French language and usage.  If you meant a place to ask technical programming questions in french... then I'm afraid I do not think we can help you... This site is in English and as such posts here are required to be in English.

Comment: _Stack Exchange is **not a forum** ARHKJHGKJH!!!!!_

Comment: easy guys.. ok, i'm going to french.stackexchange.com forum.

Answer (score 7):

There is a [French Language and Usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/) site, which is similar in purpose to the English Language and Usage site this question was migrated from. There is also an Area 51 Proposal for [Stack Overflow in French](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12692/stack-overflow-in-french). It is at 21% commitment, and when it reaches 100% there will be a public beta for it.

Comment: This proposal has been deleted.

Comment: @RO_engineer Not from what I see http://french.stackexchange.com/ seems live to me.